# socat bidirectional communication with user-defined bash function

Tags: bash, socat

So i want socat to persistently listen for connections, get the first x lines and reply back with a message. Ideally i want to use a user defined function to handle that logic but i couldn't find a way to achieve that.

My scenario:

```
client 1:

cat <(printf "line1\nline2\n") -|nc socat_server socat_port

client 2:

cat <(printf "line3\nline4\n") -|nc socat_server socat_port
```

I want to get: line1 and line3 and the clients a message (e.g. EXIT)

I've tried with:

```
exec {fd}> >(my_custom_function)
socat tcp-listen:10000,reuseaddr,fork system:"head -n1>&$fd;echo EXIT;exit"
```

but i get "Bad fd number". Any ways around this?

Comment: Pipe the output through `head`

Comment: thanks, i have updated the post to include more infomration

Comment: So you want a reusable/repeating connection listener that only outputs the first line. What fd do you want the output written to - _stdout_?

Comment: yes, but  i want it to print a message to the client as well, e.g. echo exit

Comment: Please say that in your question. There's nothing there that says you want the input written back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{fd}> file`, the value of `$fd` will be greater than 9.

With `system:shell-code`, `socat` invokes `sh` to interpret that shell code.

`sh` implementations are not required to support fds above 9 in their redirection operators. Implementations such as `dash` or `mksh` don't. Also note that ksh93 (one of the three shells with zsh and bash that supports that syntax) marks the fd obtained with `exec {fd}> file` with the close-on-exec flag, so won't be inherited by `socat` there.

So, here, you'd want to use a fd below 10:

```
exec 4> >(my_custom_function)
socat tcp-listen:10000,reuseaddr,fork system:"head -n1>&4;echo EXIT;exit"
```

Or invoke a shell that you know supports fds above 9 like zsh:

```
exec {fd}> >(my_custom_function)
socat tcp-listen:10000,reuseaddr,fork "exec:'zsh -c \"head -n1>&$fd;echo EXIT;exit\"'"
```

(not from `ksh93`).

Comment: so shouldn't the second solution be affected by the close-on-exec flag? (i tested it and it doesn't)

Comment: @tturbox, close-on-exec only affects ksh93 (hence my *not from ksh93*); zsh and bash don't set the close-on-exec flag. ksh93 will also set the close-on-exec flag on fd 4 in the first approach. Anyway ksh93 doesn't support redirecting to a process substitution.

Comment: thanks
btw i suppose another solution to the problem would be to change the default shell in which socat runs the "SYSTEM" commands since is more related with sh right?